# ¿Cómo asignar valores a un array de objetos si este no los tiene?

Tags: javascript, array, jsonarray

Tengo este array de objetos y deseo poder asignarles los valores que están guardados dentro de otro array, en caso de que no tenga el valor, asignarlo en cero. ¿Es posible lograr esto?

El array de objetos es el siguiente:

```
let data = [
{
id: 2072,
nombre_servicio: "ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN",
values: [
  {
    nombre_valor: "Jornada 8 horas",
    valor: "5000",
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Hora extra 1",
    valor: "4333"
  }
]
},
   {
   id: 2074,
    nombre_servicio: "PRODUCTOR GENERAL",
     values: [
    {
    nombre_valor: "Jornada 12 horas",
    valor: "3000",
    },
   ]
 }

]
```

El array que contiene los valores que deseo asignarles es este:

```
let p = ["Jornada 8 horas", "Jornada 12 horas", "Hora extra 1", "Hora extra 2", "Hora extra 3", "Hora extra nocturna"]
```

Lo ideal sería que el array resultante quedara algo así como esto:

```
let data = [
{
id: 2072,
nombre_servicio: "ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN",
values: [
  {
    nombre_valor: "Jornada 8 horas",
    valor: "5000",
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Jornada 12 horas",
    valor: "0",
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Hora extra 1",
    valor: "4333"
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Hora extra 2",
    valor: "0"
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Hora extra 3",
    valor: "0"
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Hora extra nocturna",
    valor: "0"
  }
]
 },
{
id: 2074,
nombre_servicio: "PRODUCTOR GENERAL",
values: [
  {
    nombre_valor: "Jornada 8 horas",
    valor: "0",
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Jornada 12 horas",
    valor: "3000",
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Hora extra 1",
    valor: "0"
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Hora extra 2",
    valor: "0"
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Hora extra 3",
    valor: "0"
  },
  {
    nombre_valor: "Hora extra nocturna",
    valor: "0"
  }
]
}

]
```

He estado haciendo algunas pruebas pero aún no logro dar con la lógica para lograrlo.

```
    let data = [
      {
        id: 2072,
        nombre_servicio: "ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN",
        values: [
          {
            nombre_valor: "Jornada 8 horas",
            valor: "5000",
          },
          {
            nombre_valor: "Hora extra 1",
            valor: "4333"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2074,
        nombre_servicio: "PRODUCTOR GENERAL",
        values: [
          {
            nombre_valor: "Jornada 12 horas",
            valor: "3000",
          },
        ]
      }

    ]

    let p = ["Jornada 8 horas", "Jornada 12 horas", "Hora extra 1", "Hora extra 2", "Hora extra 3", "Hora extra nocturna"]

    const props = new Set()

    for (let item of data) {
      for (let prop of item.values) {
        props.add(prop.nombre_valor)
      }
    }


    let newData = data.map(val => {
      let newD = {}
      for(let i = 0; i<val.values.length;i++){
        p.map(prop => {


        })
      }

      return newD

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas recorrer los datos originales y verificar si en el arreglo `values` se incluyen todas las opciones del arreglo `p` y se puede saber con el método [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) que devuelve el índice del elemento si existe o `-1` si no existe.

**Edición:** Para insertar en el mismo orden del arreglo `p`, hay que crear un arreglo vacío e ir insertando conforme se recorren los nombres, ya sea con valor en cero o el que tiene el arreglo original.

```js
let data = [
  {
    id: 2072,
    nombre_servicio: "ASISTENTE PRODUCCIÓN",
    values: [
      {
        nombre_valor: "Jornada 8 horas",
        valor: "5000",
      },
      {
        nombre_valor: "Hora extra 1",
        valor: "4333"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2074,
    nombre_servicio: "PRODUCTOR GENERAL",
    values: [
      {
        nombre_valor: "Jornada 12 horas",
        valor: "3000",
      },
    ]
  }
];

let p = ["Jornada 8 horas", "Jornada 12 horas", "Hora extra 1", "Hora extra 2", "Hora extra 3", "Hora extra nocturna"];

// Crear nuevo objeto
let newData = [];
// Recorrer datos originales
data.forEach(item => {
    let tmp = {...item};
    // Crear nuevo arreglo de valores
    let values = [];
    // Recorrer valores para verificar si existen o insertarlos
    p.forEach(value => {
        // Obtener índice en el arreglo original
        let index = tmp.values.findIndex(val => val.nombre_valor == value);
        // Si el índice es menor que cero, no existe
        if(index < 0) {
            // No existe, insertar con valor en cero
            values.push({
                nombre_valor: value,
                valor: '0'
            });
        } else {
            // Sí existe, insertar con valor actual
            values.push(tmp.values[index]);
        }
    });
    // Actualizar valores
    tmp.values = values;
    // Insertar objeto
    newData.push(tmp);
});
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Gracias maestro! como podria hacerlo para ordenarlo y quede tal cual el array de valores como este:  let p = ["Jornada 8 horas", "Jornada 12 horas", "Hora extra 1", "Hora extra 2", "Hora extra 3", "Hora extra nocturna"];

Comment: @ShotCraft3xDev, edité la respuesta para mantener ese orden.

Comment: Oh genial! muchas gracias @Triby eres un grande!